# jQuery keypress/keydown not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client, frontend

I have made a live search bar in jQuery but I have a problem!

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.searchInput', function(){ // or keypress I have the same result
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

When I press a button in the input field `.searchInput` it logs the last value it had. For example, if I type `a` it will log  (empty), then if I type `s` (so the search bar has `as` in it) it will log `a`, then if I type `d` (`asd` in search bar) it will log `as` and so on. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you are attaching the event to `keydown`. this will **capture value before the input actually happens**. if you want to capture the complete value use `keyup` event instead

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal I really need to use keydown (or keypess or anything that fires when the key is pressed. Is there anything else I can use? (both keydown and keypress don't work))

Comment: What do you mean by **need to**. Is there any requirement which says you need to or there's another event handler attached on keyup. if later is the case then you can still use keyup as all the event handlers get called

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking to capture the complete value in the text box for which you need to attach keyup event and not keydown.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.searchInput', function(){ // or keypress I have the same result
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: No. I want t use keydown but for some reason it doesn't work. It logs the value before the last one (the one that is now on screen. If I have typed `asdf` it logs `asd`. If I have typed `asd` it logs `as` etc.)

Comment: with keydown you need to have the character for current key ready and append it to the available string which is not feasible. I'd suggest you use `keyup` instead.